# RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView или по другому

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Создаю расписание, в нём есть день недели, время, предмет.
Всё хранится в json получает по средством запроса на сайт.

Сам вопрос заключается в том, как сделать внутри RecyclerView еще RecyclerView.
То есть, у нас есть день недели, до 6 штук , его мы записываем в самый вверх item, после этого записываем время и предмет и снова время и предмет, пока они не закончатся для дня недели. 
Затем переходим к новому дню недели и снова день недели сверху, потом время и предмет пока они не закончятся. и так до конца 6 дней недели.

Возможно есть какой-то способ проще, тк я знаю сколько дней недели задействовано и сколько максимум предметов будет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать к примеру при помощи `TableLayout`. То есть использовать изначально не `RecyclerView` а другой вью-элемент для этой задачи. Вот как добавляется `tableLayout`  обычном активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Weather Table"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:text="Feb 7"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:text="Feb 8"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:text="Feb 9"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:text="Feb 10"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Feb 11"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Day High"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="28°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="26°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="23°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="17°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="19°F" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Day Low"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="15°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="14°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="3°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="5°F" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="6°F" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:text="Conditions"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/hot" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/pt_cloud" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/snow" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/lt_snow" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:src="@drawable/pt_sun" >
        </ImageView>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

и вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это мне кажется будет проще чем возится с `RecyclerView` созданием адаптера для него и тд. [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/tablelayout.php) сайт первоисточник кода который я вам показал. Есть еще [ссылка_1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_table_layout.htm), [ссылка_2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) и [ссылка_3](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/) по вашему вопросу. Надеюсь что-то да пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Назовем 2-ой адаптер **InnerAdapter**, собственно сам класс адаптера не буду расписывать, главное onCreateViewHolder и onBindViewHolder сделать для него.

```
public class InnerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InnerAdapter.ViewHolder>{...}
```

Назовем 1-ый адаптер **OuterAdapter**

```
public class OuterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OuterAdapter.SomeViewHolder> {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final OuterAdapter.SomeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final InnerAdapter innerAdapter = new InnerAdapter(init);
        holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
        holder.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(innerAdapter);
    }
}
```

То есть для каждого айтема вы сделаете по своему адаптеру и инициируете нужными вам параметрами. Я использую одну инициализацию, просто во второй адаптер передаю нужные значения из некого сипска, чтобы показать этот айтем в RV отдельно.